# Where can I find the DNS cache?

Tags: 12.04, dns

I just want to see how IP addresses mapped to domain names in my local machine. Is it possible? Thanks.

BTW, it's just for fun.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using **dnsutils** to do that exactly. They are not installed by default so here you go:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

Then you can dig around the DNS System:

```
dig host.tld
```

Which will in return give you a DNS Record from your DNS Server specified in **/etc/resolv.conf**.

Caching is usually done by individual applications, like for example Firefox. To my knowledge there are only tools to flush the cache, not to read it out.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Other options to dig command:

```
dig soa host.tld

dig mx host.tld
```

For manual page of dig, follow this [LINK](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're asking about a tutorial or something like the `hosts` file in Windows. I'm a part time Windows user too. In Ubuntu, the file's under `/etc/hosts`. To edit:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```